# How do I solve this Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Can some one please help with this query:

List all Customers with multiple Meters.

I'm a complete newb so forgive me if this is an easy problem to solve..

```
Customers – minimum 20 records
Meters – min. 30 records
Meter Readings – min. 100 readings
Invoices – 1 per Meter Reading
```

I have tried the following query with no success...

```
select *
from Customers
LEFT OUTER JOIN Meters ON Customers.idCustomers = Meters.Customers_idCustomers
where Customers.idCustomers = Customers.idCustomers;
```

I have also attempted SELECT CASE queries

Thanks!

Comment: What is the structure of your data?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Find all the `Customers` records that have more than one `Meters` record associated with them? What do the tables look like?

Comment: It depends on the structure of the database, but one common solution is an inner join with `group by` and `having count(*) > 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
select c.*
from customers c
where c.idCustomer in (select idCustomer
                       from Meters
                       group by Customers_idCustomers
                       having count(*) > 1
                      )
```

In MySQL, you can also express this as a join with a group by:

```
select c.*
from customers c join
     meters m
     on c.idCustomer = m.Customers_idCustomer
group by c.idCustomer
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies, really appreciate it, as a result my problem has been resolved with the following code:             SELECT * , COUNT(*)
FROM Customers
INNER JOIN Meters ON Customers.idCustomers = Meters.Customers_idCustomers
GROUP BY Customers.idCustomers HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;

Answer (score 0):

Here is where the GROUP BY clause comes in!

```
select customers.*, count(*) meter_count
from customers
inner join meters on customers.idCustomer = meters.idCustomer
group by customers.idCustomer
having meter_count > 1
```